# document.getElementById().value not overwriting existing value

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I'm trying to pass a value to a variable on my squarespace site.  I've been able to overwrite the variable on the active page by using:

```
if (SizeInputVar >=1 && SizeInputVar <= 1500) { 
$(".sqs-money-native").html(CalcValue) }
```

However, when I go to add the product to cart, the original value is passed rather than the calculated value.

sqs-money-native is a class name.  So now I'm trying to figure out how to change the value of the ID instead, assuming that maybe if I can change the value of the ID it will add to cart.  I'm trying to use the following code:

```
  if (SizeInputVar >= 1 && SizeInputVar <= 1500) {
      var PriceChange = document.getElementsByClassName('sqs-native-money')[0].id = "PriceID12345";
      document.getElementById('PriceID12345').value = CalcValue;
    }
```

But, when I enter a value of say 120 (which would trigger the function in the first instance), nothing happens.

I'm new to coding... trying to make a Squarespace website do a few things it's not supposed to do.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  If there's no prayer of getting the value populating the class sqs-native-money to pass to cart with this method, then what's the correct method?

Comment: Is there more than one `.sqs-money-native` element in `document`?

Comment: Its just a typing miskake "PriceID12345" you are assiging this ID but using small p in getElementById, Use both common name priceID12345 It will work. see https://jsfiddle.net/bp9e07j3/

Comment: `.value` is available in `input`. If its input, then it should work, if not, use `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

There is Typo `priceID12345` should be `PriceID12345`

```js
var inpt = document.getElementsByClassName('sqs-native-money')[0];
inpt.setAttribute('id', "PriceID12345");
document.getElementById('PriceID12345').value = 100;
```

```html
<input class='sqs-native-money' />
```

Comment: Sorry... that was a typo here.  It's just a dummy var I entered as an example.  In the actual page, var references are correct.  I've fixed the issue in the question, but as that was originally correct in my website's code, unfortunately, there is still an issue.

Comment: @TomM0419 This was probably just an example too, but you also switched around 'sqs-money-native' with 'sqs-native-money'